# Emailing 13MB base64 creates extra 19MB .com

Tags: email, backup, gmail, tar, gmail-imap

My daily backup script had to be changed to create base64 file instead of regular `.tar.gz` a while ago:

```bash
Filename64="$Filename".64
cat "$Filename" | base64 > "$Filename64"
echo -e "to: $EmailAddr\nsubject: $Filename64\n" | \
    (cat - && uuencode "$Filename64" "$Filename64") | ssmtp "$EmailAddr"
```

Recently I needed to recover a file from the daily backup. I was surprised to discover gmail automatically creates a second attachment 6MB larger in `.com` format (apparently). This second unwnanted attachment is called `noname`:

[image: gmail backup 2 attachments.png]

1). ***How can I prevent `noname` creation?***

2). ***If creation unpreventable, How can I delete them en masse with gmail api?***

Comment: Why are you uuencoding the file after it has been base64'd? That seems awfully redundant.

Comment: @grawity I really don't know. I just copied commands from someone else's script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using instructions in the most up-voted answer:

- [How can I send attachment with ssmtp in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90881/200094)

that recommends:

```
echo -e "to: receiver@domain.tld\nsubject: subject\n"| (cat - && uuencode /path/to/attachment attachment.name) | ssmtp receiver@gmail.com
```

I did some new research and it seems `uuencode` was something popular 25 years ago but not so much today. The basic flaw with the bash script is `uuencode` is putting the attachment within the body of the message.

A much better method was found here:

- [5 Ways to Send Email From Linux Command Line](https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/)

Where I used the `mail` program built into my Ubuntu distribution already:

```
mail -a "$Filename64" -s "$Filename64" "$EmailAddr" < /dev/null
```